# Why is df -h size, util and dispo not corresponding to each other

Tags: lvm, size, df

When I'm using the command "df -h" I'm having the following output :

```
Filesystem                 Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root    20G    9,4G  8,8G  52% /
devtmpfs                  1,9G       0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     1,9G    1,2M  1,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     1,9G    1,0M  1,9G   1% /run
tmpfs                     1,9G       0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                     1,9G    108K  1,9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                 477M    129M  319M  29% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home   916G    279G  591G  33% /home
```

Or it says my root is of 20G with 9.4 used and 8.8 still available it's 2G that disappeared. I know a very similar question as been answered here [about the same issue with brtfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/when-using-btrfs-why-size-used-and-avail-values-from-df-do-not-match/37510#37510) and I'm just wondering if the reason could be the same here since I'm using LVM.

If not is there any way to reclaim that space that disappeared because for home there is an amazing 46G that disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra space on your file system is reserved for root. This can be changed with `tune2fs -m` (assuming of course that it is an ext2/3/4 file system). The man page gives a good explanation:

> -m reserved-blocks-percentage
>
> Set the percentage of the filesystem which may only be allocated by privileged processes.   Reserving some number of filesystem blocks for use by privileged  processes  is
>                 done  to  avoid  filesystem  fragmentation, and to allow system daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to function correctly after non-privileged processes are prevented
>                 from writing to the filesystem.  Normally, the default percentage of reserved blocks is 5%.

Other options that will affect the size of your file system are whether or not a journal is enabled (ext3/4 file systems) and space reserved to allow the file system to be increased in size. Journalling can be disabled with `tune2fs -O ^has_journal`, although I don't recommend this (it can also be resized or put on an external device - see `-J`).

> has_journal
>
> Use a journal to ensure filesystem consistency even across unclean shutdowns.  Setting the filesystem feature is equivalent to using the -j option.

Finally space reserved for increasing the size of your file system can be increased with `tune2fs -O ^resize_inode`. Once removed, this is gone for good. This will actually only reduce the size of used space.

> resize_inode
>
> Reserve space so the block group descriptor table may grow in the future.  Tune2fs only supports clearing this filesystem feature.

See also - [Reserved space for root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why)

#### Example:

```
$ truncate -s 1G testfs   # create sparse file
$ mkfs.ext4 testfs
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
testfs is not a block special device.
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
65536 inodes, 262144 blocks
13107 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=268435456
8 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (8192 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ mkdir mnt
$ sudo mount -o loop testfs mnt; df -h mnt; sudo umount mnt
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      976M  1.3M  908M   1% /home/graeme/test/mnt
$ tune2fs -m 0 testfs
tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 0% (0 blocks)
$ sudo mount -o loop testfs mnt; df -h mnt; sudo umount mnt
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      976M  1.3M  959M   1% /home/graeme/test/mnt
$ tune2fs -O ^has_journal testfs
tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
$ sudo mount -o loop testfs mnt; df -h mnt; sudo umount mnt
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0     1008M  1.3M  991M   1% /home/graeme/test/mnt
$ tune2fs -O ^resize_inode testfs
tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)

Please run e2fsck on the filesystem.

$ e2fsck testfs
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
testfs was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Filesystem does not have resize_inode enabled, but s_reserved_gdt_blocks
is 63; should be zero.  Fix<y>? yes
Resize_inode not enabled, but the resize inode is non-zero.  Clear<y>? yes
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(2--64) -4193 -(229378--229440)
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (28585, counted=28649).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1 (32703, counted=32766).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #3 (32703, counted=32766).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #5 (32703, counted=32766).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #7 (32703, counted=32766).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong (257701, counted=258017).
Fix<y>? yes

testfs: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
testfs: 11/65536 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 4127/262144 blocks
$ sudo mount -o loop testfs mnt; df -h mnt; sudo umount mnt
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0     1008M   20K  992M   1% /home/graeme/test/mnt
```