# Encrypted file system on external storage

Tags: btrfs, zfs

I use archlinux and manjaro. I recently bought an external 2TB toshiba stor.E canvio, and I planned to use it as back up. I used gpt layout and partitioned it with luks and ext4. Dolphin reports 6% full, whilst only 20kb are used. why is it so?
I decided to use encrypted zfs/btrfs on it, but I don't know any of it's basis and jargon. what's the easiest way to do so.

Comment: On Linux, you put the zfs pool on top of LUKS devices. The ZFS encryption  in newer Solaris has not been ported to ZoL (and IIRC is proprietary?) and there's little reason to do so since Linux has fine encryption with dmcrypt/LUKS

Comment: What reports those 6% full? df?

Comment: Dolphin reports so.

Comment: This question/answer might help - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116989/why-is-df-h-size-util-and-dispo-not-corresponding-to-each-other/117019